# C# Format Datalist / Datagrid based on another column in sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datagrid, datalist

quick question about how to format a cells in a datalist.

using article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510136.aspx .. I'm unsure as how to reference the row of my sql query bound to my datalist.

can someone tell me how to reference the row so I can format my datalist based on the other values in that row of my query. Do I have to make mydatreader public so it can be read by the itemdatabound event? or best way to reference it

thanks

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" GridLines="Both" RepeatColumns="4"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemDataBound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" Width="300px" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>                    
                <div>
                    <span><strong><%# Eval("col1") %></strong></span>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:DataList>

protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound
(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
    e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
    // Programmatically reference the ProductsRow instance bound
    // to this DataListItem

    //??? I need to edit below to reference the row of my query bound to 
    //my datalist

    Northwind.ProductsRow product =
    (Northwind.ProductsRow)((System.Data.DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row;


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok easy when you  know how!.. buried in the depths of google found my anwser .hope it helps someone,,

```
protected void DataList1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
        e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)  
            {
                System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord dbdr = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord) e.Item.DataItem;

                // Access Data in the Datareader
                int MD = Convert.ToInt32 (dbdr [2]);
                int MN = Convert.ToInt32 (dbdr [3]);
                DateTime DT = Convert.ToDateTime (dbdr [1]);

                if (DT <= System.DateTime.Today || MD <= MN)
                {
                    e.Item.CssClass = "red";
                }
            }
        }
```